# Remove git subtree to add git subrepo

Tags: version-control, git-subtree, git-subrepo

I had a Git repo with the `model` (the `M` in `MVC`) of the project removed and deposited into a separate repo. Then I merged it back with `git-subtree`. So I have a

`models` branch and what I think are remote tracking branches `remotes/models/master` `remotes/models/models`.

Now I just want to obliterate this subtree thing altogether, so I can move it back to a regular full repo. So I can start to use git-subtree. Now how do I remove any relics of the git-subtree?

I tried to delete local branches and remote branches. But I cannot remove remotes/models/master by `git push models --delete master`. It said:

```
remote: error: refusing to delete the current branch:
refs/heads/master To https://XXX@bitbucket.org/XXX/XXXXXmodels.git 
! [remote rejected] master (deletion of the current branch prohibited)
```

**EDIT:**

I think I just want to remove a reference to that `model` repo. I can manually remove that remote project from Bitbucket later.

Answer (score 0):

Oh! I think all I had to do is to do `git remote rm models`. Though I don't know if that leaves any junk behind.